# <a href> to .jsp file from html

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have an Servlet Project and I am deploying my code to Tomcat. This is my Java:

```
@WebServlet (name = "myFirstServlet", urlPatterns = "/myFirstServlet")
public class MyFirstServlet extends GenericServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

    public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException, ServletException {
        InputStream resource = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/index.html");
        String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        servletResponse.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pwriter=servletResponse.getWriter();
        pwriter.println(result);
    }
}
```

My index.html is located inside the resources folder. I want to make hyperlink inside my index.html to a .jsp file, which is located in the same directory. I can't even call this file in my browser manually, neither `http://localhost:8080/myFirstServlet/second.jsp` nor `http://localhost:8080/second.jsp` works. I hope you can help me, this is fairly new to me.

Comment: what the browser status you are getting

Comment: 404 on every link.